# Convert data before saving to database

Tags: symfony

Just getting started with Symfony, so please bear with me here.

I have an Entity with a field "myField" that is stored in the database as an ENUM with values 'Y' or 'N'. *(This is an old DB schema that I'm working with and trying to use symfony as an app to manipulate the data)*.

I want to represent "myField" with a checkbox for on or off (0 or 1). When the form is saved, how would I transform the value to the appropriate 'Y' or 'N' value before persisting it to the database?

I looked at [Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), and that may be where I need to go, but it seems so silly to create a new class and file just to convert that data. This is a very simple transformation.

Maybe instead I would just change the `setMyField($myField) () {}` setter method on the Entity to convert the data there? And likewise, convert it back in `getMyField() {}`? But doesn't Doctrine also use the setter methods? If so, then when Doctrine set a value, it would be the proper value (0 or 1) from the database and wouldn't need transforming. But if the form set the value, it would need transforming.

Here's the action code:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $course = new Course();

    $form = $this->createForm(new CourseForm(), $course);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($course);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('courses'));
    }

    return $this->render('PucsTestBundle:Course:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I think I could convert the data myself in the controller just before I call `handleRequest`, but that is probably not good practice.

Additionally, I have a field in the database "days" that is just a `VARCHAR` that would be something like `MTW` for Monday, Tuesday Wednesday. I want to present a checkbox for all these values, and then post-process the form submission to convert the data to the appropriate single value.

Comment: I think if you don't want to use the Transforming class you can do transforming on the Entity setter as you said

Comment: Elaborated above on why I'm uneasy with using setter methods

Comment: What about something [like this setter](https://gist.github.com/ferdynator/211b3170d99a8bf4d490)?

Comment: But I think a DataTransformer would be the best practice in your situtation!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom Doctrine Type as defined [here in the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types)

```
<?php
namespace My\Project\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

/**
 * My custom datatype.
 */
class OldBooleanType extends Type
{
    const NAME = 'OldBoolean'; // modify to match your type name

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'OldBoolean';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === 'Y'){
          return true;
        }
        if ($value === 'N'){
          return false;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === true){
          return 'Y';
        }
        if ($value === false){
          return 'N';
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

> Data transformers are used to translate the data for a field into a format that can be displayed in a form (and back on submit).